# XBox 360 randomly not signing in to Xbox LIVE

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

So occasionally when I turn on my Xbox 360 it will not automatically log in to my Xbox Live account (like it should). It hangs for minutes at time before either finally logging in or telling me that it can't login at all.

Any idea what could cause this?  It is plugged in (I am not using wireless) and the internet connection works constantly (as verified by a second machine) so its not that. What else could it be?

Comment: Connected over wired or a wireless connection? And are you assuming the internet connection works constantly based on another computer that is connected to the internet? Or the xbox can always access the internet?

Comment: wired connection. connection verified from second computer.

Comment: Do you get randomly signed out during games?

Comment: Have you done the network tests (in particular the internet and Xbox Live test) on your 360 recently?  That might give some indication of what the problem is.

Comment: no and no.  I'll give the network test a try later tonight.

Comment: When I experience this problem, my XBOX's Network Test discovers nothing. I find it pretty much useless when this problem occurs. Maybe you will have better results...

Comment: Sounds like a network issue, either on your end or your ISP. If you have a computer, try running a network diagnostic from it.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem with one of my XBOXs using a wireless connection. I originally though it was the connection so I boosted the router's signal strength but that didn't fix the problem. I then connected a wired connection and the problem persisted.

I checked my gateway's DHCP settings and it turned out that the XBOX was trying to use an IP that was no longer available and wouldn't accept a new one. My other XBOXs don't have this problem so it might be a firmware problem with a certain line of them.

The only solution I have been able to use is restart the console when it happens. I know it's not elegant but it usually works.

Comment: Have you tried giving it a static IP outside your router's DHCP range instead of sending it through DHCP every time?

Comment: No, I never even thought of that. I will give it a shot... thanks for the suggestion!